# Getting android.app.RemoteServiceException without any message on Play Console

Tags: android, android-studio, service

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2228)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8443)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:596)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

showing on play console without any specific reason